# Dataframe fill subset

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on the titanic dataset. I created a new feature with title in the names (Mr, Mrs, Master, Dr, ...). I'm using it to fill na age with median of each title.

```
titanic_data.loc[titanic_data['Age'].isnull(), 'Age'] = titanic_data.groupby('Title')['Age'].median()[titanic_data['Title']]
```

I got *cannot reindex from a duplicate axis* with titanic_data['Title]
and if I do that

```
titanic_data.loc[titanic_data['Age'].isnull(), 'Age'] = titanic_data.groupby('Title')['Age'].median()['Mr']
```

it fill with median of Mr's title,
any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do `transform`

```
titanic_data['new'] = titanic_data.groupby('Title')['Age'].transform('median')
```